# Code Mirror - How to store information in an annotation or metadata?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm using Code Mirror to create a simple code editor that creates shapes on a canvas based on certain commands. I would like to use Code Mirror's annotations to store a shape ID in the line's metadata. That way when I delete a line on the commands I can easily tell the Canvas which shape to delete.

I've been looking through the code mirror's documentation for a while now and still have no idea how I would go about implementing this.

#### How can I access the metadata (annotations) in text with CodeMirror?

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. CodeMirror has a function "markText" which can be used to give a className to the line for specific CSS styling. It can also be used to pass in any other parameters including user-created ones like shapeID.

```
// Give a line an ID
function giveLineID(lineIndex,id){
   editor.markText( {line:lineIndex,ch:0},{line:lineIndex,ch:line.length},{shapeID : id});
}

// Retrieve an ID from a line
function retrieveID(lineIndex){
  var line = myCodeMirror.getLine(lineIndex);

  var marks = cm.findMarks({line:lineIndex,ch:0},{line:lineIndex,ch:line.length});
  marks.forEach(mark => {
     if (mark.hasOwnProperty("shapeID")){
         return mark["shapeID"];
       }
     });
}
```